# Positioning DIVs with defined widths - inside DIV

Tags: css, html, positioning

There are some DIVs and SPANs with text defined widths. I need to define their exact position according to TOP/LEFT. But it is not possible with "inline-block" option.

How to set exact position with top/left and maintain their width defined width of the text ?

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/5nBtw/)

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
    <span id="test1">aaa</span>
    <span id="test2">bbb</span>
    <span id="test3">ccc</span>
</div>
<div id="container" style="float: left;">
    <div id="test1">aaa</div>
    <div id="test2">bbb</div>
    <div id="test3">ccc</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
#test1{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#test2{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#test3{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Try using a CLASS instead of an ID. As @j08691 said, IDs must be unique.E.g. `class="blabla"` and in the CSS: `.blabla{...}`

Comment: for the exact position, have you tried using `position:absolute` for the `test` classes? (If using absolute position, dont forget to set the container position to relative)

Comment: What are you trying to do? More details will help us answer...

Comment: @DanielX2010 thank you. Container position to relative and inside DIVs position absolute. :)

Comment: @Patrik glad it worked :-) I wrote the answer below just to be registered for future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the wrapper `position` to `relative`

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

and then set the inside divs `position` to `absolute`

```
#test1 {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}

...
```